# Is it needed to separate APIs for client and admin part

Tags: .net, api, architecture

I'm thinking about following task. In my project I have 2 parts:

1) an API with using by Android client
2) a back office (admin part)

My idea is to separate these two APIs from each other. By "separate" I mean that all services and database layers should be unique for Client API and Admin API.

The structure of projects will then be like this:

***MyProject.FrontOffice.API

MyProject.FrontOffice.Services

MyProject.FrontOffice.Data***

***MyProject.BackOffice.API

MyProject.BackOffice.Services

MyProject.BackOffice.Data***

Both projects are in one solution, but the problem is that quite big part of code will be duplicated in both parts.

The second idea is to not separate it and resolve it using load balancers (it will balance between several instances of the APIs; Some for the Client and some for the Admin part).

What do you think which approach better and why?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could describe what benefit you expect from that separation. Apparently, code duplication is not something you see as a benefit ---some might think it is, because it could allow the separate evolution of FrontOffice vs. BackOffice. So, what is it?

Comment: Will the API's share exactly the same code and functionality, or will there be a set of administrative endpoints and a set of client-facing endpoints that do different things?

Comment: Some Api's methods will be dublicated, but some will be used only in administration part. I mean is it not bad practice give API's methods in client API which will never used and cliet shouldn't know about it.

Comment: If the API's serve different purposes, I'd probably want to separate them for the benefits of scaling - if you need more instances to process client requests, you don't want to be forced to expose a bunch of admin API's that will never be used on some instances, and vice versa.  Nonetheless, the trade-off is that you might end up with some duplicated code - both options have merit.  You have to decide which pain you are most willing to live with.

Answer (score 5):

This is a fact.

> You should NOT separate your API based on your clients' role!

For a very simple reason. You will end up with code duplication, inconsistency and many other issues.

If you want to make any separation you need to think about business domains and encapsulation.

For example:

- MyProject.ProductsApi
- MyProject.OrderingApi
- MyProject.PaymentApi
- etc.

The functionality that is offered to a user vs an admin has to be determined and decided based on the client's access and permissions. For example based on the authentication token that is used with the request the api can determine if that user has access to this functionality or not.

There are however some cases that you want to deploy the same API (same logic and code) in more than one place. For example, if you have limitation on the resources provisioned to serve your API and during peak time your clients will cause the API to be slow or inaccessible you might not want your back office to suffer from the same issue and they should always remain functional no matter what. Therefor you do a cloud deployment and one on-premise deployment.

There are other factors involved as well, like security measurements, rate limiting, attacks, monitoring etc. which should be managed by other tools and not by separating/duplicating your API code.

Answer (score 4):

APIs code should be centralised as that's the best approach of keeping the business logic in one centralised layer rather than keeping it in 2 different places.

Keeping them duplicated in 2 projects will make the solution more prone to inconsistent results from same API in case the logic is changed in one API project but as human tendency it's possible that it gets missed in the other project or implemented differently.

Strongly recommend single business logic layer exposed via API endpoints.

Comment: can you share an article for this?